# iPhone - Trying to catch a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (seems to be a zombie problem)

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, crash, exc-bad-access

I have an app that has a strange bug.

I have registered the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification event, so when my app comes back from background, it does some things. I can play with that for hours.

But...

If I send my app to the background, put the phone in sleep mode, wait some 30-60 secondes, then wake it up, I have a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. No log in the console, crash on Thread 0 on main, nothing in the debugger, very very hard to see what happens.

If I don't wait too long, and wake up the iPhone, the app doesn't crash.

I tried to put NSZombieEnabled at YES in the environment variables of the app but that does not help.
I've checked each line of the executed code at wake up, and I don't see anything.  nil are also tested.

I've checked all my alloc/autorelease/release, retain, assign atc... code : nothing seems to be wrong.

My crash log is :

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-09-12 00:25:34.660 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MapKit                          0x31c0933c 0x31be4000 + 152380
1   MapKit                          0x31c0931c 0x31be4000 + 152348
2   MapKit                          0x31c26118 0x31be4000 + 270616
3   Foundation                      0x33628a36 0x33619000 + 64054
4   Foundation                      0x336280f6 0x33619000 + 61686
5   Foundation                      0x336202c0 0x33619000 + 29376
6   Foundation                      0x3368552c 0x33619000 + 443692
7   CoreFoundation                  0x33a69ae6 0x33a20000 + 301798
8   CoreFoundation                  0x33a69858 0x33a20000 + 301144
9   MapKit                          0x31c560c6 0x31be4000 + 467142
10  MapKit                          0x31c55e54 0x31be4000 + 466516
11  MapKit                          0x31c23414 0x31be4000 + 259092
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33a5ebb8 0x33a20000 + 256952
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33a83266 0x33a20000 + 406118
14  MapKit                          0x31c1232a 0x31be4000 + 189226
15  MapKit                          0x31c13844 0x31be4000 + 194628
16  MapKit                          0x31c134b8 0x31be4000 + 193720
17  CoreLocation                    0x34371410 0x34369000 + 33808
18  CoreLocation                    0x3436f68e 0x34369000 + 26254
19  CoreLocation                    0x3436f7e6 0x34369000 + 26598
20  CoreLocation                    0x3436b534 0x34369000 + 9524
21  CoreLocation                    0x3436d3cc 0x34369000 + 17356
22  CoreLocation                    0x3436d512 0x34369000 + 17682
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33a813fe 0x33a20000 + 398334
24  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556f8 0x33a20000 + 218872
25  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556bc 0x33a20000 + 218812
26  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47f76 0x33a20000 + 163702
27  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
28  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
29  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 0x33b0a000 + 17572
30  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 0x33b0a000 + 17744
31  UIKit                           0x32099322 0x32062000 + 226082
32  UIKit                           0x32096e8c 0x32062000 + 216716
33  MyTestApp                       0x000035b4 0x1000 + 9652
34  MyTestApp                       0x0000265c 0x1000 + 5724

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 0x33b5c000 + 186740
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 0x33b5c000 + 882436
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 0x33b5c000 + 881012
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 0x33b5c000 + 879512
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a 0x33b5c000 + 504394
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 0x30428000 + 749860
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   Foundation                      0x336465f6 0x33619000 + 185846
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 0x33619000 + 45458
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 0x33619000 + 16962
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   MapKit                          0x31be8906 0x31be4000 + 18694
7   MapKit                          0x31be87ea 0x31be4000 + 18410
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 5:
0   libz.1.dylib                    0x314b1bc0 0x314ad000 + 19392
1   ImageIO                         0x31aa0230 0x31a97000 + 37424
2   ImageIO                         0x31a9f410 0x31a97000 + 33808
3   ImageIO                         0x31a9e0d2 0x31a97000 + 28882
4   ImageIO                         0x31a9dade 0x31a97000 + 27358
5   CoreGraphics                    0x341ca052 0x341c1000 + 36946
6   CoreGraphics                    0x341c9f5c 0x341c1000 + 36700
7   CoreGraphics                    0x341c9c8a 0x341c1000 + 35978
8   CoreGraphics                    0x341e6e1a 0x341c1000 + 155162
9   CoreGraphics                    0x341f886a 0x341c1000 + 227434
10  CoreGraphics                    0x341c5e90 0x341c1000 + 20112
11  CoreGraphics                    0x341c4668 0x341c1000 + 13928
12  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x337a3658 0x33797000 + 50776
13  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x337a0c6e 0x33797000 + 40046
14  CoreGraphics                    0x341c4520 0x341c1000 + 13600
15  CoreGraphics                    0x341c43de 0x341c1000 + 13278
16  MapKit                          0x31bf6a12 0x31be4000 + 76306
17  MapKit                          0x31bf6644 0x31be4000 + 75332
18  QuartzCore                      0x3410e2fe 0x340f9000 + 86782
19  QuartzCore                      0x3412ed26 0x340f9000 + 220454
20  QuartzCore                      0x3412e7e8 0x340f9000 + 219112
21  QuartzCore                      0x3412e6a0 0x340f9000 + 218784
22  QuartzCore                      0x3412e614 0x340f9000 + 218644
23  QuartzCore                      0x340fb01a 0x340f9000 + 8218
24  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
25  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8168c 0x33b5c000 + 153228
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a7f662 0x33a20000 + 390754
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   MapKit                          0x31bf327e 0x31be4000 + 62078
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 0x33619000 + 45458
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 0x33619000 + 16962
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 0x33b5c000 + 506336
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 0x33b5c000 + 504676
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 0x33b5c000 + 506336
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 0x33b5c000 + 504676
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x41a00000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x41a00000
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x32373953      r6: 0x0015df90      r7: 0x2fdfdfec
    r8: 0x001ad110    r9: 0x2fdfdfa0     r10: 0x00155b60     r11: 0x0015df90
    ip: 0x2fdfdf1c    sp: 0x2fdfdfb8      lr: 0x2fdfdfb8      pc: 0x31c0933c
  cpsr: 0x600f0030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x12fff +MyTestApp armv7  <793dd49a7dd3301e92d7ac0108a311b1> /var/mobile/Applications/2217E735-3808-403F-9B68-3353425EA308/MyTestApp.app/MyTestApp
   0x9d000 -    0x9efff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
 0x4fa3000 -  0x4fa5fff +libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib armv7  <ee91a1927272a3528df059f4a2d1ade4> /Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30005000 - 0x30006fff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x300bb000 - 0x300bcfff  TextInput_fr armv7  <fb461d899383f106c81e650bd4754cdc> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_fr.bundle/TextInput_fr
0x300bd000 - 0x301fafff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a18bbcc41a38917fe0ae5e183d3f6b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x301fc000 - 0x302e4fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x303d1000 - 0x30426fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30428000 - 0x30a10fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30a28000 - 0x30ad5fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30ad8000 - 0x30bf8fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <b2293b8acb00a14bace7520a63f39439> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x30bf9000 - 0x30c09fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6767a1e2afbc86a1ec63dd784f5d3677> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30c98000 - 0x30d57fff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30d58000 - 0x30d60fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x30f53000 - 0x31263fff  GeoServices armv7  <f6d9eba833e82b1a9a84b38ab7672012> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x31266000 - 0x3129cfff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x313e7000 - 0x313e9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x314ad000 - 0x314b8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3164f000 - 0x31788fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x317ce000 - 0x317d3fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x319b5000 - 0x319bbfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31a3f000 - 0x31a7cfff  CoreMedia armv7  <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31a97000 - 0x31b2afff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31b40000 - 0x31b80fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31b81000 - 0x31b96fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31b97000 - 0x31be1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x31be4000 - 0x31c9afff  MapKit armv7  <69921a6353270a6f77e0816d636812e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x31c9b000 - 0x31ca7fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31cb8000 - 0x31ceafff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31ceb000 - 0x31cf4fff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31d30000 - 0x31d37fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31f68000 - 0x31f88fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32059000 - 0x32061fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x32062000 - 0x323e3fff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32481000 - 0x32483fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3256d000 - 0x3261cfff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3261e000 - 0x3262bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32ac8000 - 0x32acafff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32ad8000 - 0x32adffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32b0a000 - 0x32b44fff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32b45000 - 0x32b7cfff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32bab000 - 0x32badfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32bae000 - 0x32e48fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32f24000 - 0x32f55fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bb7ff9014b1dabec2acce95d41f05b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32f67000 - 0x32f71fff  AccountSettings armv7  <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x32f72000 - 0x32f7ffff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32fc8000 - 0x32ffbfff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x32ffc000 - 0x32ffffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x330fd000 - 0x3314dfff  GMM armv7  <2b63c1e1ce647e031a8a491e156f04d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x331c6000 - 0x331cffff  ITSync armv7  <87d409553f90e41a01afce047dc2e8fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x331d0000 - 0x3323ffff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33393000 - 0x333defff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x333df000 - 0x333e2fff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33476000 - 0x33537fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x335e8000 - 0x335e8fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33619000 - 0x33738fff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33748000 - 0x33795fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33797000 - 0x337b0fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ee16b5cee12a8947c8e511ed51ae7fef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x337ff000 - 0x33837fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x338e1000 - 0x33977fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <45665471fd70b0733b206d8166df74ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x33980000 - 0x33980fff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33a20000 - 0x33b06fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33b0a000 - 0x33b16fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33b43000 - 0x33b48fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33b5c000 - 0x33c6dfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33c95000 - 0x33d36fff  Celestial armv7  <b411f4662383ec24dbfbcde8f4c23d67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x33d6b000 - 0x33d94fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33d95000 - 0x33d99fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33f4e000 - 0x33f54fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <7e279d3b6d1e1fd7dc8c8a883255fa17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x340c9000 - 0x340f8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x340f9000 - 0x341a7fff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x341c1000 - 0x342e1fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34369000 - 0x3439ffff  CoreLocation armv7  <e19b7aa132318fc90618a663bd576461> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x343c3000 - 0x3446cfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3451f000 - 0x3460cfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3464e000 - 0x34764fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34774000 - 0x347b3fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34867000 - 0x34886fff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34887000 - 0x348c9fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x348ca000 - 0x348ccfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x348e6000 - 0x3625ffff  TextInput armv7  <557601a7d93124fd5860606f294e900a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
```

### When ran directly on the iPhone :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)  
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000  
Crashed Thread:  0
```

Lines 33 and 34 are not interpreted here but really does not help. **Symbolicating** that whole thing does not give any result but what you see there (except lines 33 and 34 that show the `main`method).

**Playing with Instrument and Object allocations**... The app just crash... No "Zombie message". As I have to test on the device to be able to sleep it down (otherwise there is no bug) and as far as I know, I can't sleep down the simulator, I can't enable zombies directly into Instruments, so I put the env var. But still no "zombie message" when the app crash.

No memory leak found by instruments using te corresponding tool.

How may I catch the error or just find it ?

**TIP : I tried to run the simulator into instruments, having the environment var NSZombieEnabled at YES, and I saw that the checkbox allowing to enable zombies is not checked by default.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still seems most likely you have a zombie.

The iOS SDK includes a tool, Instruments, that is excellent at helping track down these issues.

Check out this guide to get you going...

http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Comment: Tried this, no zombie message. And zombies are not enabled when running on the device, and that crash only happens when the device in put in sleep mode, that can't be done on my knowledge on the simulator. I put the env var to replace that, but no zombie message after the crash.

Comment: Hmmm, that sucks.  Try pulling out large chunks of the functionality down to the minimum skeleton, and see if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: I've tried this. I have isolated the route of the code, but with no result.